# Seeking QGIS plugin with functions like ArcScan?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, software-recommendations, vectorization

Is there a QGIS plugin which does raster scanning, like ArcScan.

Typical QGIS Vectorization returns very bad outputs that have thousands of 'islands'.

I require a clean and efficient vectorization process.

Comment: Could you share (click 'edit') an example of the rasters you've worked with, and the output you get in QGIS?

Comment: Isn't 1 bit (0 or 1) enough? Use gdal_translate with GeoTIFF outputformat, datatype "byte", and  creation option -co NBITS=1.

Comment: I am trying to vectorize climatic zones of India and geological maps of GSI. @Simbamangu